# Python: Using same named capture group multiple times in one regex

Tags: python, regex

Is it anyway possible to repeat a named capture group multiple times in one regex using Python?

Below is the regex (which is incorrect as there are duplicate named groups in the same regex)

```
regex = r'''Use ((?P<phn_num>(?<=(Phone: ))\d{10})?(?P<lndln_num>(?<=(landline: ))\d{10})?) 
or you can also use
((?P<phn_num>(?<=(Phone: ))\d{10})?(?P<lndln_num>(?<=(Landline: ))\d{10})?)'''
```

The input string will be either of the below:

```
 1. Use Phone: 1234567890 or you can also use Landline: 0012345678
 2. Use Landline: 0012345678 or you can also use Phone: 1234567890
```

The objective is to make one regex capture both `phn_num` and `lndln_num` as named capture groups if any of the above string is given as input.

Comment: Try it like this `Use (?:Phone: (?P<phn_num>\d{10})|landline: (?P<lndln_num>\d{10}))`https://regex101.com/r/9Z3uvs/1

Comment: Are "Use" and "or you can also use" part of string?

Comment: @Austin, Yes it is a part of string

Comment: Yes it was helpful and I used it as solution to the issue.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is not anchored, so you can use an alternation `|` instead using both named capture groups to match both variations.

Using a case insensitive match:

```
\bUse (?:Phone: (?P<phn_num>\d{10})|landline: (?P<lndln_num>\d{10}))
```

- `\bUse`  Match Use preceded by a word boundary and match a space
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `Phone: (?P<phn_num>\d{10})` Match `phone:`  and 10 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `landline: (?P<lndln_num>\d{10})` Match `landline:`  and 10 digits
- `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PEhzJh/1)

Comment: What does "Pattern is not anchored" mean?
Also, the pattern you wrote doesn't capture both groups. It captures either of one whichever is first.

Comment: @Dhananjay_Goratela By that I mean that you can get multiple partial matches. If you for example use the anchor `^` to assert the start of the string, you would only get the first results in the string. See https://regex101.com/r/GTkPA3/1 and about anchors https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html